# Why are private ?properties listed in the iOS header files?

Tags: ios, header, private

I was looking at how to do something with a UIPanGestureRecognizer in iOS6, and looked at part of the header file UIPanGestureRecognizer.h:

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_2) @interface UIPanGestureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer {
    @package
    CGPoint         _firstScreenLocation;
    CGPoint         _lastScreenLocation;
    NSTimeInterval  _lastTouchTime;
    id              _velocitySample;
    id              _previousVelocitySample;
    NSMutableArray  *_touches;
    NSUInteger      _lastTouchCount;
    NSUInteger      _minimumNumberOfTouches;
    NSUInteger      _maximumNumberOfTouches;
    CGFloat         _hysteresis;
    CGPoint         _lastUnadjustedScreenLocation;
    unsigned int    _failsPastMaxTouches:1;
    unsigned int    _canPanHorizontally:1;
    unsigned int    _canPanVertically:1;
    unsigned int    _ignoresStationaryTouches:1;
}

@property (nonatomic)          NSUInteger minimumNumberOfTouches;   // default is 1. the minimum number of touches required to match
@property (nonatomic)          NSUInteger maximumNumberOfTouches;   // default is UINT_MAX. the maximum number of touches that can be down

- (CGPoint)translationInView:(UIView *)view;                        // translation in the coordinate system of the specified view
- (void)setTranslation:(CGPoint)translation inView:(UIView *)view;

- (CGPoint)velocityInView:(UIView *)view;                           // velocity of the pan in pixels/second in the coordinate system of the specified view

@end
```

I was looking at doing something with

```
CGPoint         _firstScreenLocation;
```

This is not a  @property  so it's private.

My question then was: why are we able to see these private items? How can they be used, given that they are 'private'?

I thought perhaps it was in case we want to subclass the object, so I tried to do so as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@interface MyPanGesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer

- (CGPoint) firstLocation;

@end

@implementation MyPanGesture

- (CGPoint) firstLocation
{
    return self->_firstScreenLocation;
}

@end
```

BUT this fails to build with a link error:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIPanGestureRecognizer._firstScreenLocation", referenced from:
      -[MyPanGesture firstLocation] in Gesture.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can anyone help this confused individual?

Comment: Those aren't private properties. They are instance variables and they are marked as being in "package" scope.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [@package](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#releasenotes/Cocoa/RN-ObjectiveC/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004309-CH1-DontLinkElementID_7).
That directive means that only the classes that belong to the same image can access to that variable; that means that only the classes of UIKit can access to _firstScreenLocation.

Answer (score 0):

It fails exactly for the reason you state, it's *private* (actually *package*, which is subtly different, but it's private to you).  You can see them because those *instance variables* are being exposed to the rest of it's own *package*.  The package is `UIKit`.

You can't get at it.

(Aside: public/private status is independent of whether is is an *ivar* or *property*)

You should set up a [gesture recognizer delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and it will invoke methods while the pan is occurring.

UIPanGestureRecognizer

> Clients of this class can, in their action methods, query the UIPanGestureRecognizer object for the current translation of the gesture (translationInView:) and the velocity of the translation (velocityInView:). They can specify the view whose coordinate system should be used for the translation and velocity values. Clients may also reset the translation to a desired value.